# How do I email Active Directory distribution groups from a c# web application?

Tags: c#, active-directory, smtp, email, active-directory-group

I'm trying to send email to Active Directory distribution groups.

I know you can send mail using something like:

```
 mail.From = new MailAddress("steveb@microsoft.com");
 mail.To.Add("billg@microsoft.com");

 //set the content
 mail.Subject = "This is an email";
 mail.Body = "this is a sample body with html in it.";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

 //send the message
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
 // i seem to need this too....
 smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
 smtp.Send(mail);
```

But when I try to stick in a (valid) AD group (eg "My Test Group") in the `To` field, it kicks it out because it is not a valid email address.

I'm sure this is really straightforward, but I seem to be stuck...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You distribution group has a mail address, that's what you need to add in the 'to' parameter.

Comment: I suspected this might be the case, now if only I could find it :D

Comment: ARGH my group isn't a Distribution Group... that's why it was being stupid.

Comment: Correct, you either have to use distribution group or email enabled security group.